# Exhibiting an algorithm that determines if L = L*, given any regular language L

Tags: algorithm, membership, regular-language

I am studying membership algorithms and I am working on this particular problem which says the following:

**Exhibit an algorithm that, given any regular language L, determines whether or not L = L***

So, my first thought was, we have L* which is Kleene star of L and to determine if L = L*, well couldn't we just say that since L is regular, we know L* is by definition which states that the family of regular languages is closed under star-closure. 
Therefore L will always be equal to L*?

I feel like there is definitely a lot more to it, there is probably something I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> since L is regular, we know L* is by definition which states that the family of regular languages is closed under star-closure. Therefore L will always be equal to L*?

No. `Regular(L) --> Regular(L*)`, but that does not mean that `L == L*`. Just because two languages are both regular does not mean that they are the *same* regular language. For instance, `a*` and `b*` are both regular languages, but this does not make them the same language.

A example of `L != L*` would be the language `L = a*b*`, and thus `L* = (a*b*)*`. The string `abab` is part of `L*` but not part of `L`.

As far as an algorithm goes, let me remind you that the concept of a regular language is one that can be parsed by a DFA - and for any given DFA, there is a single optimal reduction of that DFA.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared it up for me. I was wrong to assume that L = L*.

Answer (score 1):

The implication that you stated is wrong. Closedness under the Kleene star means only that L* is again regular, if L is regular.
One possibility to check whether L = L* is to compute the minimal automaton for both and then checking for equivalence.